# Cannot register change event handler for HTML select with jQuery on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like for a JavaScript function to receive control when a user selects an item from a menu. Here is my experimental code (relevant excerpts from HTML):

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $(".myselect").on("change", "select", function() {
        console.log("TODO");
    });
});
</script>

<!-- ... -->

<form method="post" action="">
<select class="myselect">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Who knows what could be wrong here? (At this point, the event handler is never called.)

Comment: You should not bind the change event this way. make a direct change event on the class name itself.

Comment: selector place always decendent see docs http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgb2vwnw/) You can try this.

```
$(".myselect").change( function() {
    alert("TODO");
});
```

[Another Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vgb2vwnw/1/)

```
$(document).on("change", ".myselect", function() {
    alert("TODO");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a delegated handler, yet the primary and secondary selectors are the same element, so it won't work. If you need a delegated event handler (because the `select` element is added to the DOM after onload fires), you need to set the primary selector to a static parent element, like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.myselect', function() {
    console.log('TODO');
});
```

Otherwise, you can use the standard event handler:

```
$('.myselect').change(function() {
    console.log('TODO');
});
```

Comment: +1 for the reason Rory. I tried the same without knowing the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one:
   If you want to get the value:

```
$('.myselect').on('change', function(){
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxzonx82/1/